# Square matrices, ABA = A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be real $n\times n$. Is it true that if $ABA=A$ is true $B=BAB$ ?

My reasoning:
$$ABA=(ABA)BA=A  \; \Leftrightarrow A(B-BAB)A=0.$$

But as it follows from the latter, that $B-BAB=0$, if in the general case the matrix $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Do you mean to say $ABA=A$ in your first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $B$ to be the identity, then you simply need to find an $A$ with $A^2=A$ but $A \neq I$. E.g., $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$